# Template friendship based on inheritance relationship

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

I'm not sure if this is achievable. Suppose I have two class templates `Foo<T>` and `FooOwner<T>`, and a `FooOwner<T>` has a pointer member to a `Foo<U>`, where `U` is a subclass of `T`.

I want to make `FooOwner<T>` a friend of `Foo<U>`, but only if `U` is a subclass of `T`. Is that possible? If not, is there any workaround for something close enough?

```
template<typename T>
class FooOwner {
private:
    Foo<T>* p;  // This can point to a object of type Foo<U>
                // where U is a subclass of T
};

// NOTE: Foo<Derived> is always a subclass of Foo<Base>

template<typename T>
class Foo {
private:
    template<typename U>  // Constrain U to be a superclass of T?
    friend class FooOwner;
};
```

Comment: Do you mean that FooOwner has two type parameters? `template <typename T, typename U> FooOwner<T, U>`

Comment: @for_stack No, it only knows `T` and relies on `T` being a polymorphic type to work correctly. It's basically the same how we can point a `std::unique_ptr<Base>` to an object of type `Derived`.

Comment: There is a discrepancy between your description and your code. According to the description the type of `p` in `FooOwner<T>` should be `Foo<U>*`. But then, where from do you obtain the type `U`?

Comment: @Leon I should've said that "there is a pointer of type `Foo<T>` which can actually point to an object of type `Foo<U>`, where `U` is a subclass of `T`."

Comment: In general a `Foo<T>` pointer cannot legally point to a `Foo<U>` object since there is no inheritance relation between `Foo<U>` and `Foo<T>` (even if `U` is a subclass of `T`). This is possible only if you specialize `Foo<U>`. Is that the case?

Comment: @Leon Yes, `Foo<Derived>` is a subclass of `Foo<Base>` in this case.

Comment: Please make that explicit in your question

Comment: "*NOTE: `Foo<Derived>` is always a subclass of `Foo<Base>`*" But the `Foo` you show doesn't inherit from anything. Once you add the base class(es) into the code, the answer to your question will likely be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve, but maybe the type trait [is_base_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) can help you:

```
#include <type_traits>

class A {};

class B : A {};

class C {};

int main() 
{
    std::is_base_of<A, B>::value; // true
    std::is_base_of<C, B>::value; // false
}
```

You can use it with [conditional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
std::conditional<std::is_base_of<A, B>::value, A, SomethingElse>::type
  // will be A if B is derived from A, or SomethingElse otherwise
```

Or with [enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):

```
std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<A, B>::value, A>::type
  // will be defined only if B is derived from A
```

Answer (score 1):

As it seems `FooOwner` is not part of the external interface of Foo, you can declare it in `Foo`:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
private:
    template<typename U>  // Constrain U to be a superclass of T?
    friend class FooOwner;

    template< typename U>
    class FooOwner {
    public:
        FooOwner(std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<T, U>::value, U*> uptr) : p(uptr){} // (rough idea) 
    private:
        Foo<U>* p;  // This can point to a object of type Foo<U>
                    // where U is a subclass of T
    };    
};
```

You can then use [is base of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) testing or similar on the constructors of FooOwner or FooOwners methods (as sketched above).

More to the point, you can do this:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
private:
    template<typename U, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<T, U>::value>> 
    friend class FooOwner;

    template<typename U, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<T, U>::value>> 
    class FooOwner {
    private:
        Foo<U>* p;  // This can point to a object of type Foo<U>
                    // where U is a subclass of T
    };    
};
```

Both the first and second `enable_if` is not strictly required. You can remove the friendship completely (and the first enable if) and simply let `FooOwner` *exist* only if you the base-derived relation is the right. If you would like to allow the class to exist, and disallow only the friendship you can remove the second enable if. Keep a dummy template typename in that case:

```
template<typename U, typename = T> 
class FooOwner {
   . . . 
};
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/rvx5zc)

If you would like to keep FooOwner external to Foo, you could make it a template of both `U` and `T` in a similar way.